# Java - trying to restart a scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Ok, so I am making a game for a school project, and the requirements and all that are done, but I'm trying to add more by adding a high score system. The game has multiple difficulties, and I am trying to make an independent high score for each game, so that way, for example, if you get a high score of 10 on easy, then go play the game on medium, your high score isn't 10. I had the high score working when there was only one score for all the difficulties, but now when I try to do them independent, I can't get it to work. Here is some of the code (I'm obviously not going to post all of it. If you need any other code besides what I have provided please let me know.

So, here is the code that gets the high score from the text file, and if the file isn't there/hasn't been created yet, it makes it and then fills in the necessary information to set the current high score to zero.

**Note:** I do not believe this to be the problem, because this part does what it's supposed to.

```
boolean fileLoop = true;
    while(fileLoop) {
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(highScores));
            scan.useLocale(Locale.US);
            //System.out.println(scan.next());
            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                //System.out.println("loop is working");
                if(easy) {
                    if(scan.next().toLowerCase().equals(qm + "easy" + qm)) {
                        if(scan.hasNextDouble()) {
                            highestScore = scan.nextDouble();
                            System.out.println(highestScore);
                            //System.out.println("easy score worked");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(medium) {
                    if(scan.next().toLowerCase().equals(qm + "medium" + qm)) {
                        highestScore = scan.nextDouble();
                        //System.out.println("medium score worked");
                    }
                }
                else if(hard) {
                    if(scan.next().toLowerCase().equals(qm + "hard" + qm)) {
                        highestScore = scan.nextDouble();
                        //System.out.println("hard score worked");
                    }
                }
                else if(extreme) {
                    if(scan.next().toLowerCase().equals(qm + "extreme" + qm)) {
                        highestScore = scan.nextDouble();
                        //System.out.println("extreme score worked");
                    }
                }
            }
            fileLoop = false;
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            highScores = new File("highScores.txt");
            try {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(highScores));
                writer.write(qm + "Easy" + qm + " " + "0.0");
                writer.write("\n" + qm + "Medium" + qm + " " + "0.0");
                writer.write("\n" + qm + "Hard" + qm + " " + "0.0");
                writer.write("\n" + qm + "Extreme" + qm + " " + "0.0");
            }
            catch (Exception f) {

            }
            finally {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

It is this code that is the problem. When I test it, it says that `scan.hasNext()` is false.

```
if(scoreCounter > highestScore) {
            System.out.println("IF WORKED");
            try {

                scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(highScores));
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(highScores));
                while(scan.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("WHile works");
                    if(easy) {
                        System.out.println("if worked");
                        if(scan.next().toLowerCase().equals(qm + "easy" + qm)) {
                            writer.write(qm + "Easy" + qm + " " + String.valueOf(scoreCounter));
                            System.out.println("easy score worked");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try{
                    writer.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }
```

Now, correct me if I'm mistaken, but I thought that doing `scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(highScores));` reset the scanner so it would start from the top again. Also, when I keep it as is, it completely erases everything in the test file.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the file open for read with one scanner and for write with a BufferedWriter at the same time. The writer clobbers the file contents.

Comment: Ok, so how would you suggest I go about doing this?

Comment: Correction. Is there any other way to go about it using the same concept I am now. Because I do know how I could go about this, which would be having a variable for each difficulty, read the file once to store the values in said variables, then after the game is over rewrite the whole file. But is there any way to do it using only one variable like I am now?